# Receive an error from lingnutls/'Hogweed' when importing CV2

Tags: python, package

I've never seen an error like this and don't know where to start. I installed opencv with

```
conda install opencv
```

and am running Ubuntu Linux 18.04 using a conda environment named fpn. How should I even approach debugging this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: /home/s/miniconda3/envs/fpn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/../../././libgnutls.so.30: symbol mpn_add_1 version HOGWEED_4 not defined in file libhogweed.so.4 with link time reference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the recent releases of opencv packages for Conda. I have tested [all the 4.x releases](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv/files?version=) and found that the problem occurs starting from 4.3. Unless you really depend on >=4.3, forcing a version prior to 4.3 solves the problem,

```
name: test
channels:
 - anaconda
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 - python>=3.8
 - opencv<4.3
```

in my cases this installed 4.2.0. Importing `cv2` in Python works fine then. Note that using `conda update` didn't work for me and I still got the error, but I had to first [remove the environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment) and then [re-create it](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file). *I think this behavior indicates that the error is rooted in some dependency of opencv*, which is not properly down-graded when `conda update` is used.

Answer (score 2):

I don't consider this a true solution, but installing via pip with

```
pip install opencv-python
```

does work with no problem. Shouldn't there be a way to install with conda?

Comment: `opencv-python` and conda's `opencv` are two separate OpenCV packaging projects: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python vs. https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock In your case the conda one seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to happen with a mix between conda-forge and anaconda packages, which aren't compatible.
I encountered the same problem; the ultimate issue was having conda-forge configured with lower priority than anaconda. This caused the anaconda packages, which were incompatible, to be installed when there was an option.
This is, of course, a bad idea - since conda-forge assumes anaconda availability, but not vice versa